# Where to close <configuration> and <system.web> in web.config

Tags: web-config

I was getting a "Server error in '/' Application" message and in my attempts to research and fix it I've messed up my web.config file!

In my error list I keep getting a:

```
system.web start tag on line 17 does not match the end tag of 'compilation'. Line 68 position 7.
```

I've tried various locations where I think system.web should be closed without any luck.

ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2015.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-XXXX-XXXX.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ConnectPlanet-XXXX;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="cp_usersConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:XXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
    <add name="program_infoConnection" connectionString="Server=XXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
    <add name="NewImagesConnection" connectionString="Server=XXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
  </connectionStrings>
     <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
          </namespaces>
          <controls>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
          </controls>
        </pages>
        <membership>
          <providers>
            <!--
            ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
          -->
            <clear />
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
          <providers>
            <!--
            ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
            -->
            <clear />
          </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager>
          <!--
              ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
            -->
          <providers>
            <clear />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <!--
              If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
                you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
                change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
                of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
          -->
        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
          </providers>
        </sessionState>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
        </httpModules>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
          <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong you need to have matching start and ending tags.. also where is the rest of your .config settings the header is incorrect what you posted meaning the first line in the .config file..

Comment: What were you thinking to tag this "css", "c#" or even ".net"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Configuration>` is missing from the top of the file.

Where you open `system.webServer` you need to close `system.web`

```
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
```

This validates:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
      -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
          If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have fixed <configuration>, thankyou. I have previously placed the closing statement for </system.web> where you suggested and I still have the error. Just tried it again, no joy. Maybe a bug in VS2015?

Comment: @Dmur I copied it into VS2015 to validate and locate the errors in it and it seems ok in mine like that. Try cleaning the solution / rebuilding etc... it could be a false warning still loitering in studio?

Comment: A restart fixed it, thanks. But I'm now still getting my original error when I run the webpage:"
Stack empty. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty."

Comment: Now you've your config problem fixed [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question :)